# Configuring ejabberd on ubuntu ami of amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

This is my first experience with `ejabberd`. Spare me if I miss anything.

I have installed `ejabberd` server on `ubuntu 12.04 AMI on Amazon EC2`.

I have successfully installed the server, added the admin user and host in the config file and opened up required ports `5222, 5223, 5269, 5280`.

Now I tried to login the web admin interface using the admin user id and password. I could log in, BUT I could only see one section, Virtual Hosts. No Control Lists, Access rules, Nodes and Statistics Menu items on the left.
Also, when I click Virtual Hosts Menu item, the page that comes up does not show anything.

Here are the links to the screenshots

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtbq8c1863yni1x/1.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyt8b24hvfieegn/2.png

Comment: Duplicate on http://serverfault.com/questions/450388/configuring-ejabberd-on-ubuntu-ami-of-amazon-ec2

Comment: Have you found a way to install it on `ubuntu aws ec2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem was. I could successfully install same version of Ejabberd on a local machine.

Then realized it might be a problem with EC2 instance. Hence, did a fresh install on a new EC2 instance, NOT Ubuntu, but Amazon Linux.

Installed perfectly.

Comment: what is the default password for admin?

Comment: @YumYumYum : password will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config and make sure you have set the admin acl i.e. `{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "localhost"}}.` And, log in as the admin user.

Comment: Check if you have a session cookie already set in your browser. Remove that and try to log in as admin again.

Comment: After adding that line, what is the default password for admin? to have access in http://localhsot:port/admin ????